# Reload Table getting its name instead id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

i use javascript to reload my table after i input some data, my table goes like this

**BEFORE INPUT**
[image]

**AFTER INPUT**
[image]

u can see that after i input some data the table reload its `id` instead of its `name` like on the image, how can i make a way for javascript to reload its `name` instead of `id`, below are my code

> JS

```
//reload table data
    function reloadTableDataBasedOnVal(result){
        var table = tableProject.dataTable(),
                    oSettings = table.fnSettings();
        table.fnClearTable(this);

        var contents = result.content;
        for(var i = 0 ; i < contents.length ; i++){
            var project = contents[i];     
            var item=[project.cv_id,project.cv_name,project.cv_client_id,project.cn_invoice_method,project.cn_project_rate,project.cn_note,btn];
            table.oApi._fnAddData(oSettings, item);
        }

        oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();
        table.fnDraw();
    }

    function reloadTableData(){
        $.ajax({
            url : 'get-all-project',
            type : 'GET',
            dataType : 'json',
            success: function(result,status){
                if(status == successStatus){
                    reloadTableDataBasedOnVal(result);
                }
            },
            errror: function(result,status){
                errorNotification("Unknown error, Please contact your administrator!");
            }
        });
    }
```

> VIEW

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
     <tr class="odd gradeX">
       <td>{{$project->cv_id}}</td>
       <td>{{$project->cv_name}}</td>
       <td>{{$project->client['cv_name']}}</td>
       <td>{{$project->invoice['cv_method']}}</td>
       <td>{{$project->cn_project_rate}}</td>
       <td>{{$project->cn_note}}</td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

in the view i can do something like this `<td>{{$project->client['cv_name']}}</td>` since it was a simple php but in javascript i did something similar its show an error, the main code in JS is this line `var item=[project.cv_id,project.cv_name,project.cv_client_id,project.cn_invoice_method,project.cn_project_rate,project.cn_note,btn];` that code is the one make the output when the tables reloaded

Comment: Check the returning data you get in `reloadTableData` function .
if it returns ids instead of names, it's a backend side problem

Comment: yeah it's a backend, so the page only reload data from table `project`, while in table `project` there's only `client id` which is `client id` is foreign key from table `client`

Comment: Where is the code for this part ?

Comment: Looks to me like the third parameter of project.cv_client_id is wrong and should be changed to whatever the correct field is for the name. Just read through the parameters and make sure you are getting what you want.. You actually have a different number of parameters in your js code than the PHP, just go through it carefully make sure it is what should be nothing more complicated than that I don't think. (Add a space between each parameter you will be able to read it more easily - or even a new line when there are so many)

Comment: hmm im gonna look into it

Comment: @ShadyAtef which part?

Comment: The backend part which provides data for the ajax call

Comment: @ShadyAtef look at the JS, i defined the variable there, its called `var item=` and so on